# Data extract from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me because I have tried many suggestions from other sites, but can not find the solution.

I have one Dashboard Spreadsheet and nearly 30+ Department Spreadsheets (see attached snapshots).

Which would be the best way to obtain data I soon as select "Department" Name (Department name and respective worksheet and spreadsheet names are same)

Can you please help me with vba or macro?? Thank you very much!!

Spreadsheet received from different department:

[image]

Summary/Dashboard Spreadsheet

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are here to help you with code you have written, not write it all for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

First of all, you need a list with all the Sheets. For that purpose, use this function:

```
Public Function SheetsName()
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim Arr(Sheets.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To Sheets.Count - 1
        Arr(i) = Sheets(i + 1).Name
    Next i
    SheetsName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr)
End Function
```

This Function will return an array with all the sheets. Select the same number of sheets in cells on one column that it is not in use and type: =SheetsName() and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. You will get a list of your DataSheets on this range.

Later on, Use `Data Validation` on your Cell `D2`, choose list and select the range with all the sheets.

Then use this small procedure to copy:

```
Sub Test()
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set SourceSheet = Worksheets(Range("D2").Value2)
    Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
End With

LastRow = SourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
LastCol = SourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        SourceSheet.Cells(i, j).Copy Destination:=TargetSheet.Cells(i + 9, j)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

And that is all.
The Copy instruction it is not working with merged cells.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks!. It's working within the same workbook. I have 30+ workbooks that will contain individual data that will be sent of sales/marketing personal. I need to prepare the consolidated data wherein I have to extract the data from the individual files. What were the corrections required?

Comment: If it is working, close it voting as answered. If you have a new question, make it and refer to this one. If anyone has the same question it will be easier to find.